# Extracting the data frame of last 30 days from the last available date in the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I see that finding the last 30 days of the dataframe by

```
import datetime
days30=df[df.Date > datetime.datetime.now() - pd.to_timedelta("30day")]
```

This gives last 30 days considering today's date. But I am interested in getting the last 30 days that is available in the dataframe. So tried this method

```
lastdayfrom = df['Date'].max()
days30 = df.loc[lastdayfrom - pd.Timedelta(days=30):lastdayfrom].reset_index()
```

This threw error message -TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Timestamp'
How do I get the last date to use in filtering the last available date with out making date as index if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lastdayfrom = df['Date'].max()
critDate = lastdayfrom - pd.Timedelta(days=30)
days30 = df.loc[df.Date > critDate]
```

should work

Comment: gave error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'Timedelta'. lastdayform when printed gave Timestamp('2020-11-06 00:00:00').

Comment: Have you converted your 'Date' column to `datetime`? If not, use `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)` first.